# Retaliatory downvotes

Tags: support, down-votes

Somebody is going through my answers and downvoting them (in the last hour or so). Some of them are [old](https://serverfault.com/questions/986232/saving-a-copy-of-incoming-mail-for-specific-recipient-in-exim/986522#986522) but still work. And [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/988201/exim-slow-to-deliver-mails/988249#988249) for example had been marked as the accepted answer by the OP.

Is there anything I can do about it? Is it even right to downvote without explanation an accepted answer?

I'm pretty new here, I'm not complaining, just trying to understand how everything works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wait 24H if a serial downvoter. Each day a script run and the action would be removed and the user that did it will have a flag.

If after 24/48H the action was not undone you can privately contact the support, support@stackexchange.com, or use the contact us at the bottom of the page.

Explain the situation and they will be able to correctly see if it was a serial downvoting.

A moderator like me can't see much. I can see the top user that target you, but for those two specific case I can't see who, but the StackExchange employee can see that and help, where me I can't.